Stripe signature verification is failing in NextJS 14.2.3
I am trying to implement Stripe webhook in my NextJS project. I am using NextJS 14.2.3 app router.
This is my code in route.ts file
export async function POST(req: Request) {
    let lineitems;
    let event: Stripe.Event;
    const body = await req.text();

    const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY as string);
    const signature = headers().get("stripe-signature") as string;

    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            body,
            signature,
            process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_KEY as string
        );
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Webhook call is successful" });
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof Error)
            return NextResponse.json({ message: error.message });
    }
}

But in stripe dashboard, I am always getting the following error
{
  "message": "No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? \n If a webhook request is being forwarded by a third-party tool, ensure that the exact request body, including JSON formatting and new line style, is preserved.\n\nLearn more about webhook signing and explore webhook integration examples for various frameworks at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing\n"
}

I have tried everything, using "micro", "raw-body", still can not manage to figure it out.
It is working fine in localhost, but not in deployed webhook endpoint.
Please help!!!

Looks like you haven't disabled the default body parsing behaviour. Set api.bodyParser to false and try again. You can find more details on this doc

that is deprecated in next 14
